# ¿Cómo unir dos o más arreglos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Necesito unir dos o más arreglos generados en Javascript. Estos arreglos cuentan con ún string.

```
let empleadosMasculinos = ['Pedro','Juan','Alberto','Damian','Raul','Gustavo'];
let empleadosFemeninos = ['Maria','Josefina','Ana','Miriam','Julieta'];
let empleadosLimpieza = ['Jose','Graciela','Perez','Rosa'];
```

¿Cómo puedo unir todos estos arreglos en uno solo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La solución que encontré fu utilizando el [operador de propagación (*spread operator*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator):

> Permite que una expresión sea expandida en situaciones donde se esperan múltiples argumentos.

```js
let empleadosMasculinos = ['Pedro','Juan','Alberto','Damian','Raul','Gustavo'];
let empleadosFemeninos = ['Maria','Josefina','Ana','Miriam','Julieta'];
let empleadosLimpieza = ['Jose','Graciela','Perez','Rosa'];
    
let empresa =  [...empleadosMasculinos,...empleadosFemeninos,...empleadosLimpieza];
console.log(empresa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)

> El método `concat()` se usa para unir dos o más arrays. Este método no cambia los arrays existentes, sino que devuelve un nuevo array.

```js
let empleadosMasculinos = ['Pedro','Juan','Alberto','Damian','Raul','Gustavo'];
let empleadosFemeninos = ['Maria','Josefina','Ana','Miriam','Julieta'];
let empleadosLimpieza = ['Jose','Graciela','Perez','Rosa'];
    
let empresa =  empleadosMasculinos.concat(empleadosFemeninos, empleadosLimpieza);
console.log(empresa);
```

Comment: Y si es ['7:00'] ['8:00']  y quieres unirlos? Pero no son almacenados en distintos variables como en el ejemplo, sino, que lo que es el resultado de recorrer un objeto y a ese resultado quieres concatenarlo?

Comment: @Izlia, no termino de entender tu planteo, ¿podes crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable?